# Bash compare random lines in files and output a message

Tags: bash, file, compare

I'm new at scripting and i need a hand on this

I've got two files. 
In the first one i have a series of ip's and number of database connections, and in the other one i have parsed the configuration of the datasources that prints the name of the database,the maximum and minimun connections, the hostname and the ip of the database server

What i need is to compare this two files and print a message

File1

```
1.2.3.4 1
1.2.3.5 6
1.2.3.6 1
1.2.3.7 1
1.2.3.8 7
```

The first column is the ip and the second column is the numbers of simultaneous connections to the database

File 2

```
DB1 50 5      server1.domain.com 1.2.3.5
DB2 50 5    server2.domain.com 1.2.3.8
DB3 15 5      server3.domain.com 1.2.3.9
DB4 10 1    server4.domain.com 1.2.3.4
DB5 10 1       server5.domain.com 1.2.3.6
```

The first column is the name of the database, the second is the number of maximum connections , the third is the number of minimun connections, the fourth is the hostname of the server and the fifth is the ip

So, the objective is match the ip of the first file with any of the entries of the second one and when they match compare if the number of connections of the database is between the max and the min, and print a message if they are ok or if they are not ok.
Also if there's a ip that doesn´ t match in either of the files print another message

Is this possible, can someone give me a hand on this or at least point me to the solution??!

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: You may also want to check this http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR {a[$1]=$2; next} $5=a[$5]' file1 file2
DB1 50 5 server1.domain.com 6
DB2 50 5 server2.domain.com 7
DB4 10 1 server4.domain.com 1
DB5 10 1 server5.domain.com 1
```

It stores the values in the first file with an array of `a[ip]=num_connections`. Then it loops through the second file replacing the IP with number that corresponds to that specific server.

Comment: pardon, can you introduce me the best source of learning `awk`?

Comment: Hello, thanks for the tip, but will this work if for example instead of 3 or 4 lines i have 10 or 12 in the first file?

Comment: @MortezaLSC I find [Idiomatic awk](http://backreference.org/2010/02/10/idiomatic-awk/) a very good read.

Comment: @MarcosPousada yes, it should work with more lines. If not, please update your question so I can improve the answer. Basically the logic is clear: fetch col2 on the 1st field and then use it in col5 of the 2nd field.